# Ruby. Password reset link not redirected to the form (Railstutorial.org)

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, railstutorial.org, change-password

I am working on the Michael Hartl Railstutorial.org - chapter 10 - password reset.
I configured email in the development environment (Cloud9), the email is sent.
Everything works fine until the the user clicks on the email sent by the system. Instead of being redirected to the password reset form, it is going to the root. 
Compared it with the book, even with the same project code from other members - cannot find any glitch. Most likely it is something very simple, but I cannot find it :(
Any help is appreciated...

The link generated:

```
http://rails-tutorial-maxviskov.c9users.io/password_resets/7k827F5v0KPWj8kuWEvJOg/edit?email=max.viskov%40felicity-world.com
```

routes.rb:

```
  Rails.application.routes.draw do
  get 'sessions/new'
  get 'users/new'
  root 'static_pages#home'
  get  'help'     =>  'static_pages#help'
  get  'about'    =>  'static_pages#about'
  get  'contact'  =>  'static_pages#contact'
  get  'signup'   =>  'users#new'
  get  'login'    =>  'sessions#new'
  post 'login'    =>  'sessions#create'
  delete  'logout'    =>  'sessions#destroy'
  resources :users
  resources :account_activations, only: [:edit]
  resources :password_resets,     only: [:new, :create, :edit, :update]
  end
```

User Model

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessor :remember_token, :activation_token, :reset_token
  before_save   :downcase_email
  before_create :create_activation_digest

  validates :name, presence: true, length: { maximum: 50 }
  VALID_EMAIL_REGEX = /\A[\w+\-.]+@[a-z\d\-]+(\.[a-z\d\-]+)*\.[a-z]+\z/i

  validates :email, presence: true, length: { maximum: 255 },
        format: { with: VALID_EMAIL_REGEX },
        uniqueness: { case_sensitive: false }
  has_secure_password

  validates :password, presence: true, length: { minimum: 6 }, allow_nil: true

  def User.digest(string)
    cost = ActiveModel::SecurePassword.min_cost ? BCrypt::Engine::MIN_COST :
    BCrypt::Password.create(string, cost: cost)
  end

  def User.new_token
    SecureRandom.urlsafe_base64
  end

  def remember
    self.remember_token = User.new_token
     update_attribute(:remember_digest, User.digest(self.remember_token))
  end

  # Returns true if the given token matches the digest.
  def authenticated?(attribute, token)
    digest = send("#{attribute}_digest")
    return false if digest.nil?
    BCrypt::Password.new(digest).is_password?(token)
  end

  def forget
    update_attribute(:remember_digest, nil)
  end

  # Returns the hash digest of the given string. 
  def self.digest(string) 
    cost = ActiveModel::SecurePassword.min_cost ? BCrypt::Engine::MIN_COST : BCrypt::Engine.cost 
    BCrypt::Password.create(string, cost: cost) 
  end

# Returns a random token. 
  def self.new_token 
    SecureRandom.urlsafe_base64 
  end

  class << self 
    # Returns the hash digest of the given string. 
    def digest(string) 
      cost = ActiveModel::SecurePassword.min_cost ? BCrypt::Engine::MIN_COST : BCrypt::Engine.cost 
      BCrypt::Password.create(string, cost: cost) 
    end
    # Returns a random token. 
    def new_token 
      SecureRandom.urlsafe_base64 
    end 
  end 

    # Activates an account.
  def activate
    update_attribute(:activated,    true)
    update_attribute(:activated_at, Time.zone.now)
  end

  # Sends activation email.
  def send_activation_email
    UserMailer.account_activation(self).deliver_now
  end

# Sets the password reset attributes.
  def create_reset_digest
    self.reset_token = User.new_token
    update_attribute(:reset_digest,  User.digest(reset_token))
    update_attribute(:reset_sent_at, Time.zone.now)
  end

  # Sends password reset email.
  def send_password_reset_email
    UserMailer.password_reset(self).deliver_now
  end  

  def password_reset_expired?
    reset_sent_at <2.hours.ago
  end



  private

    def downcase_email
      self.email = email.downcase
    end

    def create_activation_digest
      self.activation_token = User.new_token
      self.activation_digest = User.digest(activation_token)
    end


end
```

Password reset controller

```
class PasswordResetsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :get_user,          only: [:edit, :update]
  before_action :valid_user,        only: [:edit, :update]
  before_action :check_expiration,  only: [:edit, :update] 

  def new
  end

  def create
    @user = User.find_by(email: params[:password_reset][:email].downcase)
    if @user
      @user.create_reset_digest
      @user.send_password_reset_email
      flash[:info] = "Email sent with password reset instructions"
      redirect_to root_url
    else
      flash.now[:danger] = "Email address not found"
      render 'new'
    end
  end

  def edit
  end

    def get_user
      @user = User.find_by(email: params[:email])
    end

    # Confirms a valid user.
    def valid_user
      unless (@user && @user.activated? &&
              @user.authenticated?(:reset, params[:id]))
        redirect_to root_url
      end
    end  

def update
    if params[:user][:password].empty?
      @user.errors.add(:password, "can't be empty")
      render 'edit'
    elsif @user.update_attributes(user_params)
      log_in @user
      flash[:success] = "Password has been reset."
      redirect_to @user
    else
      render 'edit'
    end
  end

  private

    def user_params
      params.require(:user).permit(:password, :password_confirmation)
    end

    # Before filters

    def get_user
      @user = User.find_by(email: params[:email])
    end

    # Confirms a valid user.
    def valid_user
      unless (@user && @user.activated? &&
              @user.authenticated?(:reset, params[:id]))
        redirect_to root_url
      end
    end

    # Checks expiration of reset token.
    def check_expiration
      if @user.password_reset_expired?
        flash[:danger] = "Password reset has expired."
        redirect_to new_password_reset_url
      end
    end    
end
```

Password reset HTML

```
<h1>Password reset</h1>

<p>To reset your password click the link below:</p>

<%= link_to "Reset password", edit_password_reset_url(@user.reset_token, email: @user.email) %>

<!--reset_password_token: @token -->

<p>This link will expire in two hours.</p>

<p>
If you did not request your password to be reset, please ignore this email and
your password will stay as it is.
</p>
```

/app/views/password_resets/edit.html.erb

```
<% provide(:title, 'Reset password') %>
<h1>Reset password</h1>

<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-3">
    <%= form_for(@user, url: password_reset_path(params[:id])) do |f| %>
      <%= render 'shared/error_messages' %>

      <%= hidden_field_tag :email, @user.email %>

      <%= f.label :password %>
      <%= f.password_field :password, class: 'form-control' %>

      <%= f.label :password_confirmation, "Confirmation" %>
      <%= f.password_field :password_confirmation, class: 'form-control' %>

      <%= f.submit "Update password", class: "btn btn-primary" %>
    <% end %>
  </div>
```

Rake routes result:

```
    Prefix Verb   URI Pattern                             Controller#Action
           sessions_new GET    /sessions/new(.:format)                 sessions#new
              users_new GET    /users/new(.:format)                    users#new
                   root GET    /                                       static_pages#home
                   help GET    /help(.:format)                         static_pages#help
                  about GET    /about(.:format)                        static_pages#about
                contact GET    /contact(.:format)                      static_pages#contact
                 signup GET    /signup(.:format)                       users#new
                  login GET    /login(.:format)                        sessions#new
                        POST   /login(.:format)                        sessions#create
                 logout DELETE /logout(.:format)                       sessions#destroy
                  users GET    /users(.:format)                        users#index
                        POST   /users(.:format)                        users#create
               new_user GET    /users/new(.:format)                    users#new
              edit_user GET    /users/:id/edit(.:format)               users#edit
                   user GET    /users/:id(.:format)                    users#show
                        PATCH  /users/:id(.:format)                    users#update
                        PUT    /users/:id(.:format)                    users#update
                        DELETE /users/:id(.:format)                    users#destroy
edit_account_activation GET    /account_activations/:id/edit(.:format) account_activations#edit
        password_resets POST   /password_resets(.:format)              password_resets#create
     new_password_reset GET    /password_resets/new(.:format)          password_resets#new
    edit_password_reset GET    /password_resets/:id/edit(.:format)     password_resets#edit
         password_reset PATCH  /password_resets/:id(.:format)          password_resets#update
                        PUT    /password_resets/:id(.:format)          password_resets#update
```

Comment: Sorry to be late - was sick. No, still the same

Comment: Done. Just recreated all the files, checked against the book and it works

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Done. Just recreated all the files, checked against the book and it works

Comment: Hm. Just found that it works only for the admin user. If the user is not an admin - then it goes to the root. Any ideas?

Comment: If you've got a follow-up question, Max, you'd be better served posting it as one. Nobody is likely to see this comment.

Comment: @MaxViskov I think anyone who signs up will get email and should be redirected to sample app only whether an admin or not. I'm still on chapter 8, will figure out soon

Answer (score 0):

It has to be a validated user, it works only for the admin because it's valid by default

I did this for the user I wanted reset password in the console first

> User.find_by_email('notadmin@gmail.com').update(activated: true)

and it worked fine